# if i want to copy the string best school into a new space in memory what are the options of statements i can use to reserve enough space for it

Tags: c

if i want to copy the string best school into a new space in memory what are the options of statements i can use to reserve enough space for it

Comment: Probably [malloc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/malloc.html) and `memcpy` (ISO) or [strdup](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) if you are using POSIX.

Comment: `strlen()` will give you the length if it is a nul-terminated string. If it has a trailing `'\n'`, then you can use `strcspn()` to get the length and trim the `'\n'` in one expression. With the length known, you then allocate `length + 1` characters of storage, e.g. `char *newstr = malloc (length + 1);` then (after validating the allocation succeeds) simply  `memcpy (newstr, oldstr, length + 1);`. The POSIX function `strdup()` does that all for you, but it is POSIX, not standard-C. (it also allocates, so don't forget to validate the return)

Comment: Just for completeness, if the compiler supports it, ```asprintf()``` is another option.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE // asprintf
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    char s[] = "best school";
    // no free(); stack allocation

    char *s2 = strdup(s);
    free(s2);

    // sizeof works here because s is an array; see later
    // strlen() which works both both array and pointers.
    char *s3 = malloc(sizeof(s));
    memcpy(s3, s, sizeof(s));
    free(s3);

    // stack allocated (i.e. < 8k including other 
    // parameters and fails badly.
    char *s4;
    asprintf(&s4, "%s", s);
    // no free(); stack allocation 

    char *s5 = calloc(sizeof(s), 1);
    strcat(s5, s);
    free(s5);

    char *s6 = calloc(strlen(s) + 1, 1);
    strncat(s6, s, strlen(s));
    free(s6);

    char *s7 = malloc(sizeof(s));
    strncpy(s7, s, sizeof(s) - 1);
    free(s7);

    // strlen(s) is determined at run-time hence s8 is a vla
    char s8[strlen(s) + 1];
    memcpy(s8, s);
    // no free(); stack allocation
}
```

and on Linux you would need to set the macro _GNU_SOURCE, usually you do that with -D_GNU_SOURCE instead of in the source itself.

Comment: Worth a mention that `sizeof(s)` is only valid for an array object in the scope where it is declared. Too often I see confusion with `sizeof(x)` used for an array passed to a function -- which just results in `sizeof(a_pointer)` Also worth cautioning to always validated the return of `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` (and `strdup`). Understand that is omitted for brevity above.

Comment: Want to, perhaps, add VLA to your answer?

Comment: @pmg is s8 what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, I edited out the initialization ( [C11 6.7.9p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p3) )